# ASP.NET C# Checkbox Realtime Validation

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, checkbox, servercontrols

Trying to get two checkbox controls to work with each other.  Pseudo-code example:

```
If Checkbox 1 is checked, 
Look at checkbox 2 and make sure it is not checked.
If checkbox 2 is checked, then uncheck Checkbox 2.
```

and Vice Versa.

I kind of have it, but it wont update until I press a submit button.  Is there a way to run the pseudo-code without pressing submit first?  I tried using:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="World1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="World1Changed" />
```

but in the codebehind file it still won't update without pressing submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your checkbox.

Comment: If you write like this, the experience is bad. Try to use asp.net ajax or javascript validation.